# showDatePickerDialog can't load DatePicker Dialog

Tags: android

I load the dialog with this method `showDatePickerDialog(this.getCurrentFocus());`. That is fine before. But I when I put inside the `setOnClickListener` for displaying the dialog on the button click, there is compiler error. The error is `The method getCurrentFocus() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}`. My code is as follow

```
    frombutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog(this.getCurrentFocus());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `new OnClickListener()` creates an inner class, which is not of type `Activity`, like the outer class.

Therefor, `this` refferes to the `OnClickListener`, not your activity. The `getCurrentFocus()`-method does not exist in the listener-class and can therefore not be found.

The way to resolve that is to explicitly say that you want the `this` from the surounding (outer) class. You do that by adding the outer-classes name before `this`:

```
showDatePickerDialog(YOURACTIVITYCLASSNAMEHERE.this.getCurrentFocus());
```