# Send activity from OnClickListner and Intent to outer class

Tags: android, performance

I have some dump quastion. I have some Onclick Listener:

```
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View myView) {
...
                if (gameInfo.isWin()){
                    //Dialogs.showWinWindow(FifteenActivity);
                }
...
    }
```

And i want to send My main activity to outer static method to show some Dialog. If I was outside the onClickListener i write:

```
        if (gameInfo.isWin()){
                Dialogs.showWinWindow(this);
            }
```

But in this case i will send OnClickListener. What i must write in this method to send my activity?

**Quatoin 2.** The same problem with restarting Activity from external method.
In mainActivity Class i use

```
    public void restart()   
{  
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

It works. But how i can use this method as "static" from external class. Something like:

```
Dialogs.restart(/*Some info?*/);
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [showDatePickerDialog can't load DatePicker Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986793/showdatepickerdialog-cant-load-datepicker-dialog)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for fast reply! and what about second question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to pass a reference of your activity when executing code in a listener or something similar, you must do this:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View myView) {
            ...
            if (gameInfo.isWin()){
                Dialogs.showWinWindow(FifteenActivity.this);
            }
            ...
}
```

Note the FifteenActivity.this, where this will return a reference to your activity.

About question 2 you must do this:

```
public static void restart()   
{  
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Which means, there's no way to call restart method in this way as you wish without declare it as static method.

Comment: I did so and it gives an error. "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getIntent() from the type Activity".

Comment: The changes above isn't covering whole implementation details, this error happens because you are calling getIntent() method from a class that isn't an activity, as far as I could see you must make Dialogs a singleton where getInstance method can take the activity as argument, pass it to a private static variable of Dialogs class and change all getIntent() to activity.getIntent(), finish() to activity.finish(), same thing for startActivity.